# Advice needed on offering category / search result filtering with minimal database querying

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, database-schema

I am working on a web store and need some advice for the best approach to take in regards to gathering data to show filtering options for price, free shipping and other options where counts of the database are involved. My script is written in PHP on mySQL.

If you look at Amazon's product categories (i.e. http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_scat_14219011_ln?rh=n%3A14219011%2Ck%3Awii&keywords=wii&ie=UTF8 ) you will see that next to the filtering options on the left hand sidebar are the number of results per category. For example, there are 163 matches in Nintendo.

I don't imagine this is stored in a table as there are so many variables you would constantly be updating the database but it also seems impractical to run a query for each filtering group to the tune of 5-6 queries per pageload.

Would it be more logical to retrieve a large dataset in cache, use PHP to filter results down and then just display back a few results or is a query of potentially thousands of items worse than running a few secondary count queries? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, category FROM table WHERE category IN() GROUP BY category
```

Comment: there would probably be a sub-query of some sort that contains the keyword IN(SELECT brand FROM brands where like "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'%") +1 tho

Answer (score 1):

> I don't imagine this is stored in a table as there are so many variables you would constantly be updating the database but it also seems impractical to run a query for each filtering group to the tune of 5-6 queries per pageload.

It actually is practical. SQL counts on small data sets (a few hundred) are very fast if you can reach them with indexes. (But see below, because it is indeed better to not do them.)

> Would it be more logical to retrieve a large dataset in cache, use PHP to filter results down and then just display back a few results or is a query of potentially thousands of items worse than running a few secondary count queries?

Doing so will eventually be slower than using SQL. As soon as your entire cache no longer fits in memory, you'll end up resorting to storing it on disk or something similar. And at that point, you'll end up going through your cached data in much the same way as if you were doing filtered full table scans in the database.

> Is there another solution?

Yes. It is to use Memcache to avoid redoing the queries over and over:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php